# Print variables Up value

Tags: arrays, web-services, soap

The  print_r returns the following value:

```
    [cobrancas] => Array
      (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 749205
                [nossonumero] => 3189028
                [dataemissao] => 1395284400
                [datavencimento] => 1395370800
                [datapagamento] => 1395284400
                [dias_vencidos] => 788
                [mora] => 0.23225806451613
                [multa] => 1.8
                [valor] => 90.00
                [valorpago] => 88.57
                [valordesconto] => 0.00
                [jurosmora] => 0.00
                [banco] => 33
                [agencia] => 1525
                [dac_agencia] => 0
                [conta] => 013000045
                [dac_conta] => 2
                [carteira] => 201
                [nome_empresa] => STOCK MIDIA INF. LTDA
                [cod_cedente] => 1640348
            )
```

But as I know it gives me values ​​of up to [ 50 ] up. How do I know the print me just [VALOR ] above 100.00 ???

```
          $Arr = count($cliente->cobrancas);
```

Comment: Posts are expected to be in English here. This could be Italian? There is no Italian Stack Overflow version. There is a Spanish one though: http://es.stackoverflow.com/ .

Comment: You might want to tag this with whatever language/framework you are using.